# Difference between 1L and (long) 1

Tags: java, casting, long-integer, literals

One of a colleague added a review comment in PR that we should use **1L** instead of **(long)1**.
The only explanation is given by my colleague is that it's convenient to use and read **1L**.
So my question is apart from readability, does **1L** offer some other benefits?

My code

```
void getUserId() {
    assert((long) 1, userService.getUserId())
}

userService.getUserId() returns long value i.e 1
assert() accepts two long object
```

Comment: Yes saves your time.

Comment: Why whould you cast a known constant from `int` to a `long` at runtime? With `L` gives all the job to compiler and "save time" at runtime, because there are no extra steps to convert `int` to `long`. And also with `L` is more readable.

Comment: `(long) 1` evaluates to the same constant as `1L`. However in the first case the number (1) is evaluated as integer whereas `1L` is always a long. Therefore `(long) 123_123_123_123` is invalid since "123_123_123_123" is outside of the integer range, whereas `123_123_123_123L` is valid.

Comment: Define jargon such as “in PR”, or delete if extraneous.

Answer (score 9):

### Explanation

Performance-wise there is no difference.

`(long) 1` is a **constant expression** (because the `1` is directly known) and hence, by the rules of the [*Java Language Specification (JLS)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html), will be a `long` after compilation already.

However, in my experience, it is far more common that people use the `long` literal and write `1L` for readability.

---

### Int literal out of bounds

You will see some differences though when you actually use `int` literals for values outside of the [32-bit integer range](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing#Range_for_storing_integers). So for example:

```
(long) 100_000_000_000
```

wont compile, you have to use a `long` literal and add the `L` to it.

---

### Bytecode

Consider the following two example snippets:

```
System.out.println((long) 5);

// versus

System.out.println(5L);
```

Now look at their bytecode:

```
0: getstatic #2 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3: ldc2_w #3 // long 5l
6: invokevirtual #5
```

Both compile to the exact same code which uses `ldc2_w` directly, loading a `long` onto the stack. So there is no explicit conversion from `int` to `long` required at runtime anymore.

---

### JLS

The JLS explains this behavior in [Chapter 15. Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html):

> Some expressions have a value that **can be determined at compile time**. These are **constant expressions** ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

Which states:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a **value of primitive type** or a String that does not complete abruptly and is **composed using only** the following: [...]
>
> - **Literals of primitive type** and literals of type String ([§3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), [§3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), [§3.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3), [§3.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4), [§3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5))
> - **Casts to primitive types** and casts to type String ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16))

So the snippet, because it only consists of a primitive literal and a cast to a primitive type, is considered a constant expression and will thus be **computed at compile-time**.

Answer (score 0):

One good reason is using the simplest way that the language provides.

Following convention is also important: I’ve been writing java since it was a baby and I’ve never before seen a `long` constant coded using a `(long)` cast.

Comment: And if you ever need a number greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you _have to_ use the `L` suffix with a long literal, otherwise you will get a compile time error. Consistency is king.